# Generating a pie chart

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to display a pie chart. The result I want to achieve:

```
Summary:

Sample  Total
A1      10
A2      20
A3      30
```

I want to show the pie chart with `10`, `20`, `30` as slices and `A1`, `A2`, `A3` as labels.

---

After reading through and following some samples I started working on 3D piechart but I keep getting following exception:

```
Filling report...
    Locale: English (United States)
    Time zone: Default
Error filling print... java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillPieSeries.evaluate(JRFillPieSeries.java:136)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.calculateVariables(JRCalculator.java:160)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:758)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:281)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:144)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

Answer (score 0):

Open "Chart data" of Pie chart in Ireport and go to "Section Value" tab there are three expression which you have to give, these are :-

```
 1 :- Key Expression (column which includes A1,A2,A3 values)
 2:- Value expression (Should be integer - column which includes 10,20,30))
 3:- Label expression (Should be string ) 
         - if you want to convert integer column to sting use this - 
            **$F{column which includes 10,20,30}.toString( )**
```

Comment: Hi Sharad, Thanks for the help but it did not work. Sample and Total are Column header (static text box) and Under Sample we have A1,A2,A3 are static text fields again and Under total Column we get the data from sql DB. Any suggestion will be a big help. Thanks for your time

Comment: Also under fields i have A1,A2,A3 and not the header as theses are the DB Fields which i am fetching

Comment: I resolved by adding key,value and label for all A, B, and C one at a time.